# Thread на C# с примера Java

Tags: java, c#, visual-studio

Портирую с Java на C# код. Есть фрагмент:

```
private void updateWeatherData(final String city) {
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            final JSONObject json = WeatherData.getJSONData(getActivity(), city);
            if (json == null) {
                _handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getActivity().getString(R.string.place_not_found),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                _handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        renderWeather(json);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

На C# поток не может что-либо содержать, а точнее не берёт ничего, что идёт после объявления. То есть, если я в методе напишу это или что-либо подобное:

```
new thread()
```

То компилятор попросит закрыть фигурные скобки, хотя кода далее много. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как открыть поток, чтобы без проблем продолжить код в методе?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Идиоматический способ на C# такой:

```
Task.Run(() =>
    {
        JSONObject json = ...;
        if (json == null)
        {
            // ...
        }
        else
        {
            // ...
        }
    });
```

С другой стороны, если вам нужно вернуть выполнение в главный поток, то вам имеет смысл воспользоваться async/await, и написать что-то такое:

```
async Task updateWeatherData(string city)
{
    var a = getActivity();
    var json = await Task.Run(() => WeatherData.getJSONData(a, city));
    if (json == null)
        Toast.makeText(a, a.getString(R.string.place_not_found), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else
        renderWeather(json);
}
```

Видите, насколько проще?

Comment: На самом деле очень здоровский совет, спасибо! Вроде сейчас всё намного лучше, чем было. Остался момент, вместо getActivity я раньше использовал (Context,Assets, city) или просто (Context city), в этом варианте так не выйдет. Если я напишу this.Activity as MainActivity (я не в майн активити пишу все это), проканает?

Comment: @BlackerAndrew: Я, к сожалению, не в курсе, я полный профан в Андроиде (это ж Андроид, да?). Простите!

Answer (score 4):

В C# это можно записать так:

```
new Thread(() =>
{
    // здесь код, выполняемый в потоке
})
.Start();
```